# integers and uiimage in uipicker view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit, uipickerview

i currently have a uipicker with two components. The first contains images and works fine, the second however requires integer values.

Is this possible since the following callback method returns a UIView type not integer? Surely there must be a way around this?

-(UIView *)pickerView

any help would greatly be appreciated, many thanks

Comment: just return a UILabel display the int value

Comment: i tried that but it crashes or do you mean implement the -(UILabel*)pickerView prototype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this?

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{   
    switch (component) {
    case 1:
    {
        UILabel *intvalue = view?(UILabel *)view:[[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 40)] autorelease];
        intvalue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value];
        intvalue.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        intvalue.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        return intvalue;
        break;
    }'
}
```

Comment: thanks a bunch adali, i realised i was adding a ccLabel which of course would never work :)